# mysql select max row by one field when using group by

Tags: mysql

```
mysql> select * from test;
+----+--------+------+------------+---------+
| id | title  | tag  | date       | content |
+----+--------+------+------------+---------+
| 38 | title1 | xx   | 1514521364 | 1       |
| 39 | title2 | xx   | 1514521365 | 1       |
| 40 | title3 | xx   | 1514521366 | 1       |
| 41 | title4 | xx   | 1514521367 | 2       |
| 42 | title5 | xx   | 1514521368 | 2       |
+----+--------+------+------------+---------+
5 rows in set (0.01 sec)
```

this is my test table. l need get the result like follow:

```
+----+--------+------+------------+---------+
| id | title  | tag  | date       | content |
+----+--------+------+------------+---------+
| 40 | title3 | xx   | 1514521366 | 1       |
| 42 | title5 | xx   | 1514521368 | 2       |
+----+--------+------+------------+---------+
```

l group by `content` field, and need select row by `max(date)`, because l need the `id` field correct.

sql may like `select id, max(date), content from test group by content;`

l tried some way, but failed. l really a rookie in mysql.

Answer (score 0):

Try This:-

```
SELECT *
FROM test
WHERE date IN (SELECT MAX(date)
               FROM test GROUP BY content);
```

Comment: This won't work if (for example) content=2 also has a date matching the maximum value for content=1

Answer (score 0):

This query will do what you want. It `JOIN`s the table to a list of the maximum dates for each content based on the content and date matching, thus giving you the correct values of `id`, `title` and `tag`:

```
SELECT t.*
FROM test t
JOIN (SELECT content, MAX(date) AS maxdate
      FROM test
      GROUP BY content) t1
ON t1.content = t.content AND t1.maxdate = t.date
```

Output:

```
id  title   tag     date        content
40  title3  xx      1514521366  1
42  title5  xx      1514521368  2
```

[SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/fca08/6)